# python programs to count letters in each word of a sentence

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python and I need a program that not only counts the words from an input sentence but also counts the number of letters in each word. This is what I have so far. Any help would be very much appreciated!

```
def main():
    s = input("Please enter your sentence: ")
    words = s.split()
    wordCount = len(words)
    print ("Your word and letter counts are:", wordCount)
main()
```

Comment: Are you expecting a TotalWordCount and a TotalLetterCount for the single sentence input?

Comment: both. I used a for loop to get the count.
       s = input("Please enter your sentence: ")
       words = s.split()
       wordCount = len(words)
       print("You word and letter count is:", wordCount)
       count = 0
       for ch in words:
        count += 1
        print(len(ch))
main()

Answer (score 7):

You can generate a mapping from words to word lengths, as follows:

```
s = "this is a sentence"
words = s.split()
letter_count_per_word = {w:len(w) for w in words}
```

This yields

```
letter_count_per_word == {'this': 4, 'a': 1, 'is': 2, 'sentence': 8}
```

Comment: If you don't want to be bothered with what the *words* are, however, you can get the letter count by `letter_count_per_word = [len(w) for w in words]`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I haven't seen this method before. I finished the code, but now I'm not sure how to format the output. I want the number of characters per word to appear on the same line. Do you know how I can do that? 'format' in the print function?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Python has a collections class called Counter which will count the number of occurrences of each word for you.

```
from collections import Counter

my_sentence = 'Python is a widely used programming language'
print Counter(my_sentence.split())
```

### Output

Counter({'a': 1, 'used': 1, 'language': 1, 'Python': 1, 'is': 1, 'programming': 1, 'widely': 1})

Answer (score -1):

Try following code

```
words = str(input("Please enter your sentence. "))

print (len(words))
```